# Alternative Plotting to Cytoscape Network

Tags: networking, plot, cytoscape

I would like to hear alternative plotting suggestions for a complex metabolomic network plotted in Cytoscape.

I have tried to plot with different layouts but it didn't work.

I have no codes for that it was plotted in cytoscape with abs fold change values and tanimoto similarity score.[image: comparison metabolite differences between two conditions]

Comment: Greetings.  There are lots of different layout algorithms and each layout algorithm has it's own tuning capabilities.  The real question is what you are trying to achieve with your visualization.  One possibility would be to create subnetworks from each of your large connected components.  At any rate, it would be helpful to have a better idea of what you are actually to show with your network.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. Actually in the notes we have two groups which are color coded for green and red. Simples idea is to show that there are more green colors than red one meaning when we treated mice we had more changes on green color coded metabolites. Does that make sentence?

Comment: OK, got it.  So, first, I would hide the labels -- they don't help and only obscure the message.  Second, make the edges much more transparent.  Third, make the nodes larger (much larger).  Finally, don't use red/green.  Let me say that again -- NEVER use red/green unless you are absolutely positive that everyone looking at the figure is not red/green colorblind, or you provide a separate visual channel.  If that still doesn't provide the effect you want, you might just use a grid layout unless the clusters are relevant.

Comment: Will give a try as you suggest. Thank you so much for your time.